# Issue with Foundation 5 block-grid-default-spacing to be set horizontally and vertically

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

Here is my code :

```
<div>
      <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
          <li><img src="img/split-img/mufe-header1-1.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/split-img/mufe-header1-2.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/split-img/mufe-header1-3.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
          <li><img src="img/split-img/mufe-header1-4.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/split-img/mufe-header1-5.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="img/split-img/mufe-header1-6.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Newly user of Foundation, i'm trying to customize the default spacing of the block-grid component in my scss file :

```
 $block-grid-default-spacing: rem-calc(5);
```

The result is that the horizontally spacing is correct but not the vertically one since the spacing is set in every left and right side of the grids so it might be doubled sometimes. Please check out https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehlVJ.jpg

Can anyone help me to fix this issue since I want the spacing (horizontally and vertically) to be unique.

Comment: Answered below instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe block-grid spacing has any effect on vertical spacing. You would have to specify this in another CSS file that targets those block-grids and adds your vertical spacing.

So I might try the following:

```
$block-grid-default-spacing: 20px;
```

I would make this a px value so you can match it in your targeted CSS. Or you can leave it to the default, and handle all spacing in your custom CSS.

Then I would add a class to your ul's, so you can target them in separate CSS.

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 image-grid">

.image-grid li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

or if you wanted to leave the $block-grid-default-spacing alone..

```
    .image-grid li {
      margin: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: It didn't help since Foundation'scss isn't customizable that much on all the parameters. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Foundation's SCSS->CSS that you see there in the settings.scss file are just the default variables for the generic theme. You can add any of your own SCSS->CSS on top their base variables/files to provide whatever customization you need. For example, in your app.scss file, add an import to your own file, maybe called "mytheme-block-grid.scss" and then define your own styles there to override foundation's.